# Does Snowflake have log messages similar to Teradata?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does Snowflake have log messages which are similar to the log messages provided by Teradata like the one below which contains the following details

- Query / statement executed on the database
- Result summary of running the query
- Elapsed time
- Actual result which shows the rows
- Error codes, if any

  .Logon e/fml, password, acctid
  *** Logon successfully completed.
  *** Total elapsed time was 3 seconds.
  .SET SEPARATOR ' | '
  SELECT * FROM department;
  *** Query completed. 5 rows found. 4 columns returned.
  *** Total elapsed time was 3 seconds.

  DeptNo | DeptName      | Loc |  MgrNo

  ---

  ```
   500 | Engineering   | ATL |  10012
   700 | Marketing     | NYC |  10021
   300 | Exec Office   | NYC |  10018
   600 | Manufacturing | CHI |  10007
   100 | Administration| NYC |  10011
  ```

  .LOGOFF
  *** You are now logged off from the DBC.
  .EXIT;

Comment: Most or all of this is available in the query history tab: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-history.html

Answer (score 0):

You can find this information in `QUERY_HISTORY`:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html

> Retrieve up to the last 100 queries run by the current user (or run by any user on any warehouse on which the current user has the MONITOR privilege):

```sql
select *
from table(information_schema.query_history())
order by start_time;
```